# HowTo prevent AlertDialog.Builder cancelOnTouchOutside

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

With ordinary dialog we can use cancelOnTouchOutside
but with
AlertDialog.Builder we can't use it
Is there a way to do it?

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.setTitle(getString(R.string.tx_newgame));
alert.setMessage(getString(R.string.tx_newgamesure));
// Réponse Oui
alert.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    dialog.dismiss(); // ferme le dialogue et commence une nouvelle partie
    //....
  }
});
// Réponse Non
alert.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    dialog.cancel();
    //....
  }
});
=> alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);  // need fix here
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's very simple, follow these steps**

```
AlertDialog dialog;
 AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

 dialog=alert.create();
 //CanceledOnTouchOutside
 dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Comment: Thanks, but we should add this at the end and replace the show from alert to dialog:     Dialog dialog=alert.create();
    //CanceledOnTouchOutside
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.show();

Answer (score 0):

Just set

```
alert.setCancelable(false);
```

Comment: it is not as I can't cancel it, it is about if someone is touching outside the box, it should not cancel: it should stay as a nodal dialog

Comment: box - you mean bounds of dialog, don't you ?

Comment: alert.setCancelable(false); does the stuff you want - it's make dialog not cancelable by touch - but you still can close it via alertDialog.dismiss()